# Gradient of the log likelihood for energy based models

Tags: likelihood, derivative

Coming from this recent paper [Your Classifier is Secretly an Energy Based Model And You Should Treat it Like One](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.03263), they give the following definition...

$$
p_\theta(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{\exp(-E_\theta(\mathbf{x}))}{Z(\theta)}
$$

with $Z(\theta) = \int_x \exp(-E_\theta(x))dx$, then consequently it says that it can be expressed as

$$
\frac{\partial \log p_\theta(x)}{\partial\theta} = \mathbb{E}_{p_\theta(x')}\Big[\frac{\partial E_\theta(x')}{\partial \theta} \Big] - \frac{\partial E_\theta(x)}{\partial \theta}
$$

I tried getting there myself but I am not sure if this is correct or not

$$
\begin{aligned}
\nabla_\theta \log p_\theta(x) &= \frac{1}{p_\theta(x)} \nabla_\theta p_\theta(x) \\
&= \frac{Z(\theta)}{\exp(-E_\theta(x))} \Big(-\exp(-E_\theta(x))\nabla_\theta E_\theta(x)Z(\theta)^{-1} + \nabla_\theta Z(\theta)^{-1} \exp(-E_\theta(x)) \Big) \\
&= -\nabla_\theta E_\theta(x) + Z(\theta)\nabla_\theta Z(\theta)^{-1} \\
&= -\nabla_\theta E_\theta(x) + Z(\theta)\nabla_\theta \int_x \exp(E_\theta(x)) \\
&= Z(\theta) \int_x \exp(E_\theta(x)) \nabla_\theta E_\theta(x) -\nabla_\theta E_\theta(x) \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The second step comes from the product rule, and everything is just simplified from there. The sign inside the exponential and the exponent of $Z(\theta)$ are the opposite of what they should be. (If it were $Z(\theta)^{-1}$ and $\exp(-E_\theta(x))$ then I would have the expectation perfectly)

I must have gone wrong somewhere, but I do not see what I did. Can anyone spot the mistake?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue emerges in the evaluation of the second term in line $(3)$ and $(4)$ of your derivation. Note that

$$\nabla_{\theta} Z(\theta)^{-1} = \nabla_{\theta} \frac{1}{\int_x \exp(-E_{\theta}(x))\, dx} \neq \nabla_{\theta}\int_x \exp(E(_{\theta}(x)) \, dx.$$

Instead, we have

$$\nabla_{\theta} Z(\theta)^{-1} = \nabla_{\theta} \left( \frac{1}{Z(\theta)} \right) = \frac{-\nabla_{\theta}Z(\theta)}{Z(\theta)^2}.$$

Hence,

\begin{align}Z(\theta)\nabla_{\theta} Z(\theta)^{-1} &= \frac{-1}{Z(\theta)}\nabla_{\theta} Z(\theta) \\
&= \frac{-1}{Z(\theta)} \nabla_{\theta} \int_x \exp(-E_{\theta}(x)) \, dx \\
&= \frac{-1}{Z(\theta)} \int_x \nabla_{\theta}  \exp(-E_{\theta}(x)) \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{Z(\theta)} \int_x \exp(-E_{\theta}(x)) \nabla_{\theta} E_{\theta}(x) \, dx, ​
\end{align}

which yields the expression you seek.

There are some technicalities concerning differentiating under the integral, or commutativity of $\nabla_{\theta}$ and $\int_x$ operators, on which this derivation relies. If the functional form of $E_{\theta}(x)$ is such that $p_{\theta}(x)$ parametrises an exponential family, then there are no issues. If not, then depending on whether the support of $p_{\theta}$ and hence limits of integration in $\int_x$ are finite or infinite, then you will need [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) or [Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) to justify this. See *Statistical Inference* by Casella and Berger (2004) if you are looking for simple tests of the latter without recourse to analysis results pertaining to Lesbesgue integration.

Comment: thanks for the great answer